# Add column name as alias in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

How can I add the value of a column name as an alias to another column?

```
 MAX(CASE WHEN col_name='YYYY' AND property LIKE 'xxx' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS col_name
```

where col_name is a column that can take multiple strings and I want to put the string matching the case as an alias name for the pivoted column.

Thank you

Comment: You would use `as yyyy_xxx` or whatever column name you want.

Comment: and if I do not want to put explicitly the col_name value is there a way to use something like $col_name to get that string value? I may also want to process it applying some regex functions. Thank you

Comment: . . Not in a `select` query directly.  However, if you construct the query in an application, you can do that.